# Tracking header changes with call to action in Google Optimze

Tags: google-optimize

I can't really find too many articles on examples where you have a box with a header and call to actions in that box. 
We set up an A/B test that switches out the header language on an element container.

Mainly we have a cart page that has a box for donations with 3 donation options.  We don't change the options.  What we do change is the language on the page. 
HOWEVER, there is also a the "Check Out" button on the page as well.

When a user selects a donation option (which is a button), it does a post back to the cart and adds the donation amount to the cart.

So I am having trouble deciphering if the conversion that it is pulling is a conversion where someone hit the donation option or the Checkout button. 
How would I tell the track the differences in the conversion?

Any ideas? How would I tell the success if the headers are causing users to click the donation amount or if they are just going to checkout.  Do I need to add some sort of other trigger to track the success of the header and they click one of the donation buttons?

Comment: Do you have any events set up in connection to the checkout event?

Comment: @kgrg, This is kind of what I need to know is how to track those events through Optimize. I do have click event tracking via a custom JS Tag in Google Tag Manager, it is the combination of header and which option the user selected that would be beneficial for us to know.